# Multiplying count in SQL range by cost per unit

Tags: sql, sqlite, inner-join, gis

I've got an order system that relates to a grid area. My first calculation gives the number of customers in a 50 x 50 grid square (split into square of 10 x 10):

```
SELECT 
    10 * (customer_x / 10),
    10 * (customer_y / 10),
    COUNT (*)
FROM t_customer
GROUP BY 
    customer_x / 10,
    customer_y / 10 
ORDER BY 3 DESC;
```

I now need to work out how to calculate which grid square has made the most money from orders. Order totals are kept in an Order table and the two tables are as follows:

`t_customer:` (where customer_x and customer_y are 2 figure coordinates)

`customer_id, customer_x, customer_y`

```
t_order:

order_id, order_total, order_datetime, customer_id
```

I'm sure I have to do an inner join, but am not sure how to implement this into the grid square range, and whether or not the above query can be included. I'm using sqlite3 and any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you just need to join in the orders table and use that for the aggregation.  This is a pretty simple modification to your original query:

```
SELECT 10 * (c.customer_x / 10), 10 * (c.customer_y / 10),
       COUNT(*) as num_orders,
       SUM(o.order_total)
FROM t_customer c JOIN
     t_orders o
     ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
GROUP BY c.customer_x / 10, c.customer_y / 10 
ORDER BY SUM(o.order_total) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: That works great, thanks very much fro the help. Just getting my head around the logic.